# span coming outside of div and not fitting exactly

Tags: html, css

I have converted my problem into a simple code. I wanted span class block with class in to be exactly wrapping up the div class. It is coming outside diagonally at right bottom out of div. Can somebody help. Idea is that in the larger problem I am trying to solve, want to be able to create border sometimes with div and sometimes with span. Can somebody help in how to make these div and span just on one another?

```css
.checker {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 10px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.in {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="checker" id="uniform-deleteradio_0"><span class="in"></span></div>
```

Update on 14/3. Thanks for all the answers. Some of the techniques would make the inner span come within external div. But, what I want is like both div and span to be wrapped one on top of another. Say, I give border to either div or span, it should look like single border and both div and span look like single element. That's the situation in my actual project and I cannot eliminate either of div or span. span has one image as background (checkbox) and outer div has a border.

Comment: remove width/height from the div? let's simply make the browser calculate the height/width for you

Comment: I'm at a loss as to what you're after. Can you explain this a little more clearly please?

Comment: `checker` is 17x17 on the inside and `in` is 37x37 - how it will fit *inside* then...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your inner span is exceeding the size of the surrounding div box because of the border. You could make your outer div bigger (+20px) to fit the inner box.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height` and `width` from the outer div, so it is allowed to be big enough to fit the inner sized div. I also changed the display property of the inner div to `block`.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <style>
    .checker { border: 10px solid green; display: inline-block; }
    .in { width: 17px; height: 17px; border: 10px solid red; display: block; }
    </style>
    <div class="checker" id="uniform-deleteradio_0"><span class="in"></span></div>
    </html>
```

Comment: or you can keep the inline-block and use `vertical-align:top` to avoid the bad whitespace at the bottom

Comment: Thanks Simran, Temani and all for the help. Updated the description to give more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the height and width of .checker to 'auto'. Fixed width and height will of course put any child to outside the div if it will not fit

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me finally. 
margin-left: -10px 
margin-right: -10px